# Using an array as search criterea for find command

Tags: bash, find, array

I'm wondering if it's possible to declare an array of file types to then be searched with via the find command?

So

```
fileTypes=(*.omf *.jpeg *.xml *.otf)
find . -name ${fileTypes}
```

Instead of:

```
find . -name '*.omf' -o -name '*.jpeg' -o -name '*.xml' -o -name '*.otf'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that is supported natively by the find command, but you could loop over the find command with this one liner to achieve the desired functionality:

```
for type in ${fileTypes[@]};do find -name "${type}"; done
```

Just one note, if you define the array using wildcards in a directory where any files match the pattern then globbing will perform the filename expansion on the file and place that filename in your array. This will cause that iteration of the find command to only search for that filename, and not all files with that extension. You could avoid this potential downfall by defining the array without the wildcards:

```
fileTypes=(.omf .jpeg .xml .otf)
```

Then add the wildcard to the find command: `find -name "*${type}"`

Comment: To follow up way after the fact.. I was using fileTypes[@] instead of fileTypes[*]. Is using '@' more for just printing out all the elements rather than iterating against the array?

Comment: Both have have very similar operation with a small nuance, explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3355375/5495979 
I actually prefer using [@] as well, and to be honest I use that and [\*] interchangeably, but had I of used double quotes around the the array variable in my answer, it would have broken the solution, so yes, continue using [@] because in this case it will be robust. Glad you brought this up because I am going to change that in my answer for a more robust solution.